# google app script list view behavior different on pc browser vs mobile

Tags: google-apps-script

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZwRKIb6Y3DrXBQ3hkRK0DebHPV5GeeozuAJ45it-3Hnu0iX8/exec

please check it out in webpage it works on pc but not in android browser / android webview. any clue ?

related thread was [google script unable to update web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764814/google-script-unable-to-update-web-page)

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: Miten, please provide details about what you mean by "does not work in android". What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works as any other listBox on android browser, you should modify your code if this layout is not good for you. But it also generates an error when one select an item, see screen capture below
[image]

Comment: hi,  if you use it on pc broswer you do not see any such errors.  I would expect similar UI as well as behavior on android browser / webview in activity.  if html select list shows up like that in android browser what can I use ? I do not understand you mention use different layout.  thanks.

Comment: I changed code to not use listbox object and instead just added labels.