# Google Apps Script DialogBox show from clienthandler

Tags: event-handling, google-apps-script, client-side, show-hide, dialog

I am trying to create an 'Are You Sure' type dialog using a DialogBox. So when someone clicks a button, a popup shows with yes/no buttons for the user to confirm they wish to proceed with the action.

I have figured most of it out, however I can't figure out how to make it show without calling back to a server handler.

I tried using the show() command with a Client Handler, but it doesn't work. I tried using setVisibility() also, but couldn't get this working either.

I don't want to have to make a round trip just to show the dialog box for the obvious user experience reasons.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: did you try a search on this forum ? here is the result that might be interesting for you :http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5Ddialogbox

Comment: When you're asking a question here, it's best to show your work. Sure, you used the show() method - but the fact it didn't work says you did something wrong. Maybe you forgot to return a UI Instance [like this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764814/google-script-unable-to-update-web-page/17788550#17788550). Maybe you did something else that another set of eyes could see. How would we ever know? </rant>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small snippet i have created for just this reason. It does however use a server handler...

```
function MsgBox(message, title, id, buttons, handler, modal, autoHide){
  this.message=message;
  this.title=title;
  this.id=id;
  this.buttons=buttons;
  this.handler=handler;
  this.modal=(modal)?true:false;//Default is false
  this.autoHide=(autoHide)?new Boolean(autoHide):true;//Default is true

  this.position={};
  this.position.top=100;
  this.position.left=550;
  this.position.width=400;

  this.button={};
  this.button.ok={name:"Ok",id:"OK_BTN"};
  this.button.yes={name:"Yes",id:"YES_BTN"};
  this.button.no={name:"No",id:"NO_BTN"};
  this.button.cancel={name:"Cancel",id:"CANCEL_BTN"};
  this.button.retry={name:"Retry",id:"RETRY_BTN"};

  this.addButton=function(btn){
    try{
      if(this.buttons==undefined){this.buttons=[];}
      if(typeof btn=="string"){btn=this.button[btn.toLowerCase()];}//If a string, convert to the intended object
      if(btn.name==undefined){return this;}//Check if we've actualy got one of the buttons by checking one of it's properties. Exit if not.
      this.buttons.push(btn);
    }catch(err){
      Logger.log(err.message);
    }
    return this;
  };

  this.show=function(e, app){
    if(app==undefined){app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();}
    if(this.buttons==undefined){this.buttons=[this.button.ok];}//The default is one 'Ok' button
    var dialog=app.createDialogBox(true,true).setId(this.id).setText(this.title);
    dialog.setPopupPosition(this.position.left,this.position.top);
    dialog.setGlassEnabled(this.modal);
    dialog.setAutoHideEnabled(this.autoHide);
    var basePanel=app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(this.position.width+"");
    basePanel.add(app.createLabel(this.message).setWordWrap(true).setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px"));//Add message
    var buttonPanel=app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("ButtonPanel");
    basePanel.add(buttonPanel.setStyleAttribute("display", "block").setStyleAttribute("margin-left", "auto").setStyleAttribute("margin-right", "auto"));
    var btnHandler=app.createServerHandler("msgBox_close").addCallbackElement(buttonPanel);
    for(var i=0;i<this.buttons.length;i++){
      var btn=app.createButton(this.buttons[i].name, btnHandler).setId(this.buttons[i].id).setTag(this.id);
      if(this.handler!=undefined){btn.addClickHandler(this.handler);}
      buttonPanel.add(btn);
    }
    dialog.add(basePanel).show();
    return app;
  };
}

function msgBox_close(e, app){
  if(app==undefined){app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();}
  var dialogId=e.parameter[e.parameter.source+"_tag"];  
  app.getElementById(dialogId).hide();
  return app;
}
```

Here is a smal example how to use it.

```
var msgBox=new MsgBox("Testing 123...", "This is a test", "MyMsgBox");
msgBox.show(e, app);
```

By using the '_tag' parameter to reference its own ID you make a clean roundtrip with little hassle.

You can add standard buttons by calling the .addButton() function.
Example:

```
msgBox.addButton("yes").addButton("no");
```

By passing your own handler, you can call your own functions.
Example:

```
function myOwnHandler(e, app){
    if(app==undefined){app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();}
    if(e.parameter.source.indexOf("YES_BTN")!=-1){

    }
    return app;
}
```

Comment: Tim. Thanks a lot for this code mate. Took me a little while to get my head around it, and to figure out how to pass the handler, but I've got it working. I think I will stick to the server handler, and use your code, as it is far more sophisticated than my attempt.  Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Tim, to make the dialog box properly modal I think the line should be: <br/><br/>this.autoHide=(autoHide)?new Boolean(autoHide):false;//Default is true<br/><br/>Then if you pass false it prevents the user closing the dialog box by clicking outside of it.

Comment: can't quite get the hang of formatting the response :)

Comment: In my example myOwnHandler(e, app) we reference the .source parameter. This will hold the ID of the element that has called the serverHandler. This will always be one of our buttons. so by comparing the ID stored in the source we can determine which button was pressed.